Component not rendered for the route match
I have the below route config.
const ContentOutput = lazy(() => import('../Projects/components/ContentOutput'));

.........
{
   title: 'Outputs',
   path: '/outputs',
   pathVars: {
      ':projectNumber': projectNumber,
      ':trade': 'mechanical'
   },
   exact: true,
   icon: <DownloadOutlined />,
   contentComponent: ContentOutput,
   isEnabled: () => isAuth && isProject,
   forceLogin: true
}
..........

I have the below component contentoutput that looks like as below,
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Card, Layout, Tabs } from 'antd';
import { useParams, useNavigate, Navigate, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { NoStyleLink } from '../../common/utils/utils';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const BasisOfDesignTabsContainer = () => {
  console.log('basis');
  const { projectNumber, trade } = useParams();
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [isMechanicalBodDownloading, setIsMechanicalBodDownloading] = useState(false);
  const [isElectricalBodDownloading, setIsElectricalBodDownloading] = useState(false);
  const [activeTabKey, setActiveTabKey] = useState(trade);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Attempting to navigate:', projectNumber, activeTabKey);
    if (activeTabKey !== trade && projectNumber && activeTabKey) {
      navigate(`/projects/${projectNumber}/${activeTabKey}/outputs`, { replace: true });
    }
  }, [activeTabKey, projectNumber, navigate, trade]);

   useEffect(() => {
     if (trade !== activeTabKey && projectNumber && trade) {
       setActiveTabKey(trade); // Update the active tab to reflect URL changes
     }
   }, [trade, projectNumber]);

  const handleFetchBasisOfDesign = async (trade, setIsBodDownloading) => {};

  const tabItems = [
    {
      key: 'mechanical',
      label: 'mechanical',
      children: (
        <BasisOfDesign
          handleFetch={() => handleFetchBasisOfDesign(activeTabKey, setIsMechanicalBodDownloading)}
          isBodDownloading={isMechanicalBodDownloading}
        />
      )
    },
    {
      key: 'electrical',
      label: 'electrical',
      children: (
        <BasisOfDesign
          handleFetch={() => handleFetchBasisOfDesign(activeTabKey, setIsElectricalBodDownloading)}
          isBodDownloading={isElectricalBodDownloading}
        />
      )
    }
  ];

  return (
    <Layout.Content key={activeTabKey} style={{ background: '#fff' }}>
      <Tabs
        type="card"
        activeKey={activeTabKey}
        onChange={(key) => setActiveTabKey(key)}
        items={tabItems.map((item) => ({
          key: item.key,
          label: (
            <NoStyleLink to={`/${projectNumber}/${item.label}/outputs`}>{item.label}</NoStyleLink>
          ),
          children: item.children
        }))}
      />
    </Layout.Content>
  );
};

const ContentOutput = () => {
  const { projectNumber, trade } = useParams();
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log('Rendering ContentOutput', { projectNumber, trade }, location.pathname);

  if (location.pathname !== `/projects/${projectNumber}/${trade}/outputs`) {
    return <Navigate replace to={`/projects/${projectNumber}/${trade}/outputs`} />;
  }

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/projects/:projectNumber/:trade/outputs"
        element={<BasisOfDesignTabsContainer />}
      />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default ContentOutput;

My problem is that I am not able to render the component BasisOfDesignTabsContainer even if the route matches with this http://localhost:3000/projects/88945-00/mechanical/outputs and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Please let me know if you have any suggestions on why I cannot render the component.
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Where and how is ContentOutput rendered that renders BasisOfDesignTabsContainer? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve].
